# convert 9.2532 decimal into binary matlab

Tags: xcode, matlab, binary

I use de2bi(x) but it help only for integer i want to convert for digit with point decimal into binary

```
de2bi(x)
```

convert this 9.2553 into decimal with fraction part also convert into binary format in Matlab if possible than without function file with code want output

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB, of course, already stores double values in binary using [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format. All we have to do is somehow get MATLAB to show us the bits.

One way is to use [typecast](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) which makes MATLAB interpret a set of memory locations as a different type. In this case, we'll make MATLAB think a `double` is a `uint64` and then send the "integer" through `dec2bin`. We'll have to do some decomposition on the string after that to get the actual value.

Note: This currently only works with positive values. If you need negative values too, I'll have to make some adjustments.

```
function binstr = double2bin(d)
   d = double(d);   % make sure the input is a double-precision float
   ieee754_d = dec2bin(typecast(d, 'uint64'),64);   % read double as uint64
   % IEEE-754 64-bit double:
   %    bit 1 (msb) = sign bit (we'll ignore this for now)
   %    bits 2-12   = exponent with bias of 1023
   %    bits 13-64  = significand with leading 1 removed (implicit)
   exponent = bin2dec(ieee754_d(2:12))-1022;   % 2^n has n+1 bits
   significand = ['1' ieee754_d(13:64)];
   if (exponent < 1)   % d < 1, so we'll need to pad with zeros
      binstr = ['0.' repmat('0',1,-exponent) significand];
   else   % d >= 1; move exponent bits to the left of binary point
      binstr = [significand(1:exponent) '.' significand(exponent+1:end)];
   end
end
```

Test run:

```
>> double2bin(9.2532)
ans = 1001.0100000011010001101101110001011101011000111000100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ad hoc solution:

Expand by `2^44` (to get an integer value).
Convert integer result to binary.
Reduce by `2^44` by placing "decimal" point.
(`2^44` is the smallest power of 2 expansion that gives an integer result).

Code sample:

```
expandedRes = dec2bin(9.2553*2^44);
res = expandedRes[1:end-44, '.', end-43:end);
```

Result:

```
res =

1001.01000001010110110101011100111110101010110011
```