# Matlab Error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to convert decimal number to binary. It works for regular decimal numbers. However, when I enter (25.10) I get the subscripted error.

My code below.

```
function [binary] = decimal2binary(decimal)
% floor : rounds towards minus infinity
% rem : remainder after division
% num2str : converts numbers to strings
% fliplr : flips string bits to get correct order
i = 1.0;
q = floor(decimal/2);
r = rem(decimal, 2);
% THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS binary(i) = num2str(r(i));
while 2 <= q
    decimal = q;
    i = i+1;
    q = floor(decimal/2);
    r = rem(decimal, 2);
    binary(i) = num2str(r);
end
binary(i + 1) = num2str(q);
binary = fliplr(binary);
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert 9.2532 decimal into binary matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826668/convert-9-2532-decimal-into-binary-matlab)

Comment: What should the output be for input `25.10`?

Comment: @LuisMendo converting a decimal number to binary... my function is having an issue with decimal points ...

Comment: As a side note, Matlab has the function dec2bin, with dec2bin(25.10) yielding '11001' (which is 25). I don't think your code is able to produce the binary form of the decimal part (0.10 = 0*0.5+0*0.25+0*0.125+1*0.0625...) yielding '0.0001...'.  Maybe provide some context as to why you'd like to convert a decimal number.

Comment: @FrankBoccia What approach is your code using? Have you traced the execution using the debugger to see the values of the variables when the error occurs? What do you expect `binary(i) = num2str(r(i));` to do (or is it `binary(i) = num2str(r);`?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the line with the error is indeed:

```
binary(i) = num2str(r(i));
```

Then, when calling the function with argument 25.10, before reaching this line we have:

```
i=1
r=1.10000
num2str(r(i)) = '1.1'
```

That's why the attribution

```
 binary(i) = num2str(r(i));
```

Does not work. In Matlab, binary(1) is a 1x1 char array. You are trying to fit a 1x3 char array ('1.1') to it.

Comment: How do I fix this error? Do I have to make another variable a double to store this information?

Comment: You should have rounded r(i) to have it equal to 1 and ignore the decimal part. Then you need a different logic to work with the decimal. Recalling my previous comment as a hint: (0.10 = 0*0.5+0*0.25+0*0.125+1*0.0625...) yielding '0.0001...'